# Flutter/Dart/Firestore - Group documents by day in an AnimtedList

Tags: list, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, grouping

How can I group messages between users by day? So far it just adds to the list and sorts it by day but I can't seem to add a gap between the messages that were sent in past days. The list is being displayed in an `AnimatedList()`

Code :

```
List<Message> _messages = [];

... 

_initMessages() { // Being called in the initState
  APIs().chats.messages(
    chatID: widget.chat.chatID,
    onEmpty: () {
      if (mounted)
        setState(() {
          this._isLoading = false;
        });
    },
    onAdded: (m) {
      if (mounted)
        setState(() {
          if (m.type == 'Image') {
            m.message = NetworkImage(m.message);
          }
          this._messages.add(m);
          this._messages.sort((a, b) => a.createdAt.compareTo(b.createdAt));
          if (mounted) this._listKey.currentState.insertItem(this._messages.length, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
          this._isLoading = false;
        });


    },
    onModified: (m) {
      int i = this._messages.indexWhere((message) => message.messageID == m.messageID);
      if (mounted)
        setState(() {
          this._messages[i] = m;
          this._messages.sort((a, b) => a.createdAt.compareTo(b.createdAt));
          this._isLoading = false;
        });
    },
    onRemoved: (m) {
      int i = this._messages.indexWhere((message) => message.messageID == m.messageID);
      if (mounted)
        setState(() {
          this._messages.removeAt(i);
          this._messages.sort((a, b) => a.createdAt.compareTo(b.createdAt));
          this._isLoading = false;
        });
    },
    onFailure: (e) {
      print(e);
    });
}
```

It shows the messages in order but when I changed it to an `AnimatedList` it gives me an error:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/animated_list.dart': Failed assertion: line 279 pos 12: 'itemIndex >= 0 && itemIndex <= _itemsCount': is not true.
```

Kinda a two-part question, group the documents by day and try to get it to work in an `AnimatedList`. The date is of the Firestore Timestamp type.